# Python regarding .split in file

Tags: python

Hello can anyone please help out with this?

this is the content of my txt file

```
DICT1 Assignment 1 25 100 nothing anyway at all
DICT2 Assignment 2 25 100 nothing at all
DICT3 Assignment 3 50 100 not at all
```

this  is my code

```
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())

with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\DICT1 Assessment Task.txt", "r") as r:
    for line in r:
       print(line.strip().split())
```

my output of the code is

```
['DICT1', 'Assignment', '1', '25', '100', 'nothing']
['DICT2', 'Assignment', '2', '25', '100', 'nothing', 'at', 'all']
['DICT3', 'Assignment', '3', '50', '100', 'not', 'at', 'all']
```

Now my question is , how do i make the output to be

```
['DICT1', 'Assignment 1', '25', '100', 'nothing']
['DICT2', 'Assignment 2', '25', '100', 'nothing at all']
['DICT3', 'Assignment 3', '50', '100', 'not at all']
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the output of you program? I can see there at least the wrong indentation on line `home = str(Path.home())` and a missing separator in the split call.

Comment: tell us what is the output as well

Comment: editted the question and  @Antoine thanks for pointing that out

Comment: have you checked whether the separators in your text file were spaces or tabs ?

Comment: it is just a space. no tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem here is your input file, the separator in this file is a space but you also have some values with spaces to retrieve.

So you have two choices here:

1. You either change the input file to be *comma separated values*, i.e.:

   ```
   DICT1, Assignment, 1, 25, 100, nothing anyway at all
   DICT2, Assignment, 2, 25, 100, nothing at all
   DICT3, Assignment, 3, 50, 100, not at all
   ```
2. You change your script to unpack manually the end of lines once you got every other items:

   ```
   from pathlib import Path
   home = str(Path.home())

   with open(home + "\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\DICT1 Assessment Task.txt", "r") as r:
       for line in r:
           splittedLine = line.strip().split(" ")
           taskId = splittedLine[0]
           taskTitle = splittedLine[1]
           weight = splittedLine[2]
           fullMark = splittedLine[3]
           description = " ".join(splittedLine[4:])

           print("taskId: " + taskId + " - taskTitle: " + taskTitle + " - weight: " + weight + " -fullMark: " + fullMark + " - description: " +            description)
   ```

Comment: you're correct.  i never thought of changing the content of my file

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `maxsplit` parameter of the `split` method

```
line.split(maxsplit=5)
```

Of course if the format of the lines in your file is similar and you are using python 3.

For Python 2.x you should use

```
line.split(' ', 5)
```

Comment: and in python2.7 you can do `line.split(' ', 5)`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I might have incorrectly assumed he is using Python 3

Comment: the output of maxsplit =5 is ['DICT1', 'Assignment', '1', '25', '100', 'nothing'], it worked halfway but i want the 'Assignemnt 1'  instead of 'Assignment', '1' .

Comment: if that is the case what is the format of your file? why don't you put `,` between values?